# What's the best way to store parsed XML before writing it to a file?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I've been working on a [Python script](http://pastebin.com/D9DkQdEv) to parse [XML](http://pastebin.com/vRRxfWiA) and create a new file from it. Heres a simple overview of the XML structure:

```
<script>
    <stage id="stage1">
        <init>
            <variable id="year" value="2012" type="Integer"/>
            <variable id="femaleCloseDate" value="06/04/1955" type="Date"/>
            <variable id="runFemaleCheck" value="True" type="Boolean"/>
            <if>
                <condition><![CDATA[$gender$ == "F"]]></condition>
                <then>
                    <executeMethod class="engineclass_validation" method="femaleCheck">
                        <arguments>
                            <variable id="dob"/>
                            <variable id="femaleAgeBracket"/>
                            <variable id="todaysDate"/>
                        </arguments>
                        <return>
                            <variable id="femalePensionAgeCheck"/>
                        </return>
                    </executeMethod>
                </then>
            </if>
        </init>
        <execute>
            # same stuff as init
        </execute>
    </stage>
```

The problem with this is that it simply reads each line at a time & outputs the line depending on the tag. How could the data be stored for each element in order to use it after everything has been read?

I imagine I could have two classes, one to parse the XML and another to create a file for each stage using all of the information stored during parsing.

I've no problem parsing the XML as I've already been working with that, but how can I store whats parsed and output it like this instead of a line at a time from the XML;

```
if gender == F:
    import engineclass_database
    eeid = engineclass_validation.femaleCheck(dob, femaleAgeBracket, todaysDate)
else:
```

Is this best done using dictionaries? And how then could the data from all those separate sets from outside each class/function be accessed?

Comment: I would note that XML doesn't really seem an appropriate tool for what you are trying to do - you just appear to be making a very verbose version of your script.

Comment: Very true. Which is why I've got the job of trying to make a tool to convert the XML to Python. Its a huge pain, especially as this is the first time I've used Python!

Comment: Ouch, this is like something I'd expect to see on *The Daily WTF*. Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah tell me about it. Updating an old system is no fun. It seems a job that's been put off for a long time and I've got the pleasure of doing it!

Comment: In "And how then could the data from all those separate sets from outside each class/function?" could the data be WHAT?

Answer (score 5):

Use an xml parser (I suggest lxml) to load your xml, and to create new DOM trees.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using etree to parse everything & haven't heard about SAX so I'll have a read up on this & hopefully it'll help.

Comment: @marksweb Your question has changed since I wrote this answer. If the problem is output not as XML, then the solution is to just not write any output until the end.

Comment: Its not changed, I've just better phrased it around the previous "this is the output I want" part to clearly state that I can already get that output, just not the bit where I want to insert a list of parsed elements in to a line. Thats where my problem is. How to store that data and build the structure later.

Comment: @marksweb Yes, that's a change. In any case, it's not clear what your question is really driving at: of course you could use dictionaries, or objects, or possibly other datastructures. There isn't anything in your question that strongly suggests any particular approach. Why don't you just try any approach that seems appropriate?

Comment: Fair point. Not knowing too much about it I wasn't sure if there was a particular approach which would prove better than anything else.